# The result keeps saying: "Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but String was expected"

Tags: kotlin, grammar

I have ran the following code on [play.kotlinlang.org](https://play.kotlinlang.org) but the result keeps saying: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but String is expected`
(I made some changes from the original example code)

I have no idea why its inferring type is Unit.
I thought I announced the returning type as String.
Is the type of `println()` Unit or have I just wrote the whole `ring` function wrong?

```
fun main(){
    val squid:(String)->String={str->println("I'm $str")}
    //ring(::rabbit)
    ring(squid)
}

fun rabbit(str:String):String{
    println("I'm $str")
    return str
}

fun ring(carrot:(String)->String){
    carrot("a appetiting squid")
}
```

Comment: `println()` does not return any-thing. You may wanna put like this: `{ str -> println("I'm $str"); str }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Animesh pointed out you aren't returning a `String` n `squid`

`val squid:(String)->String` defines a lambda that takes in a String and returns a String

```
{str->println("I'm $str")}
```

A lambda will return the value on the last line of the lambda, but in this case that last value is `println("I'm a $str")`

`println` return `Unit`, or rather, it doesn't return anything (which is what `Unit` represents). So if you still want to print the String AND return it, rewrite it like so:

```
{ str -> 
   println("I'm $str")
   str // This string is the value that will now be returned.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution Rafa! Was real helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda returns `Unit` because `println` returns `Unit`.

You can write that line as follows:

```
 val squid:(String)->String={str-> str.also { println("I'm $it") }}
```

The standard `also` extension function lets you use the value in an expression (because it returns the value itself) but "also" do something with it first.

Comment: Thank you for another solution herman! Hope you have a great day